# DOMPDF error http error 500

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I want to print an PDF file for my table in my db whenever the client ask to have some hard copy of the records. Unfortunately when I print the record or convert it into pdf format it keeps saying:

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Even when I get rid of the table in try to put any html element on it.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//index.php
//include autoloader

require_once '../autoload.inc.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

//initialize dompdf class

$document = new Dompdf();

$html = '
    <style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
';

//$document->loadHtml($html);
$page = file_get_contents("cat.html");

//$document->loadHtml($page);

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pdf");

$query = "
    SELECT *
    FROM preschoolers 
";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$output = "
    <style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Interp</th>
    </tr>
";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row["p_id"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>
            <td>$'.$row["interp"].'</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}

$output .= '</table>';

//echo $output;

$document->loadHtml($output);

//set page size and orientation

$document->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

//Render the HTML as PDF

$document->render();

//Get output of generated pdf in Browser

$document->stream("Webslesson", array("Attachment"=>0));
//1  = Download
//0 = Preview


?>
```

I am using DOMPDF.
Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As mentioned in comments, it would help to see what the error is. A 500 error is from your web server indicating the underlying technology encountered a fatal error. Check your PHP logs.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I use DOMPDF. I use this all the time. Version I am using is 0.7.0. I'm providing a full tested sample, and so you should know that if it doesn't work, it's your HTML. DOMPDF can be picky about what it successfully uses for HTML. Try my sample code, but make sure the line that includes autoload.inc.pdf is really the location of autoload.inc.pdf.

```
<?php

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

function write_file($path, $data, $mode = 'wb')
{
    if ( ! $fp = @fopen($path, $mode))
        return FALSE;

    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);

    return TRUE;
}

function pdf_create( $html, $filename, $output_type = 'stream', $dompdf_cfg = [] )
{
    // Remove all previously created headers if streaming output
    if( $output_type == 'stream' )
         header_remove();

    // Load dompdf and create object
    require_once '../autoload.inc.php';
    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', TRUE);
    $options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

    foreach( $dompdf_cfg as $k => $v )
        $dompdf->$k($v);

    // Loads an HTML string
    $dompdf->loadHtml( $html );

    // Create the PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    // If destination is the browser
    if( $output_type == 'stream' )
    {
        $dompdf->stream( $filename );
    }

    // Return PDF as a string (useful for email attachments)
    else if( $output_type == 'string' )
    {
        return $dompdf->output( ['compress' => 1] );
    }

    // If saving to the server
    else 
    {
        // Save the file
        write_file( $filename, $dompdf->output() );
    }
}

$html = '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <style>
        h1{color:red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>';

pdf_create( $html, 'Webslesson', 'stream' );
```

This should work for you, and if it does and then doesn't with your HTML, post your HTML here, and we'll try to figure out what's wrong with it. I guess there's also a chance that your DOMPDF version is not the same as mine. Let me know if there is some problem you are having. Again, this code is tested, and used all the time.

Comment: I tried it still the same error. Maybe because the version of my dompdf? I am using dompdf master.

Comment: @JayzdeVera, did you try my code all by itself, and still the same error? If that's the case, then you'd need to look at the server logs for more info.

Comment: you mean in my server?

Comment: Yes, the server should have an error log, and tell you what is happening.

Comment: When I try to run it it says that localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Yep, and somewhere on the server is the error log that will give you the details. What kind of computer/server is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152482/discussion-between-brian-gottier-and-jayz-de-vera).